# How to debug Google Load Balancer "Error: Server Error"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using `gke-l7-global-external-managed` (which is effectively [Google Cloud L7 load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https)) and I was getting error:

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

After many hours of debugging, I narrowed down the issue to a single header value in the HTTP response that is causing the load balancer to panic and exit with this error.

Where are the logs about the underlying error surfaced?

As far as I can tell, they are not in the log explorer or anywhere else that I was able to check in the Google Cloud panel.

Comment: What is the header and value? Load balancer logging must be enabled: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring#logging